# How can you get overlapping matches in regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Say I have a regex `r"(([a-zA-Z]+)(&|\|)([a-zA-Z]+))"`, and a string `"groupone|grouptwo|groupthree|groupfour"`.

If I run

`re.findall(r"(([a-zA-Z]+)(&|\|)([a-zA-Z]+))", "groupone|grouptwo|groupthree|groupfour")`

it returns:

`[('groupone|grouptwo', 'groupone', '|', 'grouptwo'), ('groupthree|groupfour', 'groupthree', '|', 'groupfour')]`

This is not my desired result. I would also like grouptwo and groupthree to be matched, like this:

`[('groupone|grouptwo', 'groupone', '|', 'grouptwo'), ('grouptwo|groupthree', 'grouptwo', '|', 'groupthree'), ('groupthree|groupfour', 'groupthree', '|', 'groupfour')]`

What do I need to correct about my regex to make this possible?

Comment: With normal `re` by capturing inside a lookahead, eg: [`(?<![^|])(?=(([^\W_]+)([&|])([^\W_]+)))`](https://regex101.com/r/BdTHba/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module for this. Unlike the standard library [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), it supports overlapping matches.

```
import regex

regex.findall(r"(\b([a-zA-Z]+\b)(&|\|)(\b[a-zA-Z]+)\b)", "groupone|grouptwo|groupthree|groupfour", overlapped=True)

[('groupone|grouptwo', 'groupone', '|', 'grouptwo'),
 ('grouptwo|groupthree', 'grouptwo', '|', 'groupthree'),
 ('groupthree|groupfour', 'groupthree', '|', 'groupfour')]
```

N.B. please note the addition of word boundaries (`\b`) in the pattern. If you were to keep your original pattern, you would get a bunch of unwanted matches as well using this method.

Comment: Was working on the same, came up with `regex.findall(r'((\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)([&|])((?2)))'`